# run time error in dynamically allocated array to delete an element in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++14, c++17

I have written a program in C++ to delete an element in a dynamically allocated array. I can see the array with the deleted element but after that, it produces some errors which I can't understand. I have included the images to the error as I wasn't able to copy the error message.
I'm using:

Debian 9, 32 bit

Compiler clang.

IDE code::blocks.

The code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *ar,arsize,lp1,lp2,lp3,lp4,ele,pos;
    ar=nullptr;
    cout<<"enter the size of array to be created:- "; cin>>arsize;
    ar=new int[arsize];
    if(!ar)
    {
        cout<<"Aborting";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
    cout<<"enter the elements for array:- ";
    for(lp1=0;lp1<arsize;lp1++)
    {
        cin>>ar[lp1];
    }
    cout<<"Enter element to be deleted:- "; cin>>ele;
    for(lp2=0;lp2<arsize;lp2++)
    {
        if(ar[lp2]==ele)
        {
            ar[lp2]=0;
            pos=lp2;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(lp3=pos;lp3<arsize;lp3++)
    {
        ar[lp3]=ar[lp3+1];
    }
    ar[arsize]=0;
    cout<<"new array is:-"<<endl;
    for(lp4=0;lp4<arsize-1;lp4++)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<ar[lp4]<<endl;
    }
    delete[]ar;
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Do not use images of errors](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Indent your code properly. Remember that `new` never returns a null pointer. Avoid C-style arrays and `new []`, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You want to track allocated size AND data size. What if you don't find an item to delete? You read/write past the end in a few places. You could delete with memmove. This is why you use std::vector instead :)

Comment: Use [sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) to quickly check for such errors. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/010459270dccd886). If you compile with debug information, the address sanitizer will show the offending line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `ar[arsize]`, which doesn't exist.

Remember, C++ arrays are 0 indexed.

So try `ar[arsize-1]` instead

Answer (score 2):

This code has undefined behavior:

```
 ar[lp3]=ar[lp3+1];
```

Since `lp3` points to the last element, `ar[lp3+1];` is out of bounds.

Also:

```
ar[arsize]=0;
```

Writes out of bounds. Maximum valid index is `arsize-1`, since indexing starts with zero. This last line corrupts your heap.